# Save a set of images into a MySql DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following form (in wich I put 4 file input tag), I would like to save this 4 pictures into my database named "mybase".

Here is the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" >
<head>
   <title>Envoyer une image</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
   <style type="text/css">
    label {
        display:block;
        width:150px;
        float:left;
    }
   </style>
</head>
<body>


<h1>Envoyer une image</h1>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="traitement.php" method="post">
    <p>

 <?php

$serveur_db = 'localhost';
$user_db = 'root';
$pass_db = '';
$base_db = 'mybase';


$query = "SELECT * FROM pays";

$res = $conn->query($query);
?>

<select name="truc">

<?php

while($line = $res->fetch()){
echo '<option value="'.$line['id_pays'].'">'.$line['nom_pays'].'</option>';
}

?>
</select>

<br>
        <label for="nom">Picture1 : </label><input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" /><br />
        <label for="image">Image : </label><input type="file" name="image" id="pic1" /><br />

                    <label for="nom">Picture2 : </label><input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" /><br />
        <label for="image">Image : </label><input type="file" name="image" id="pic2" /><br />


                    <label for="nom">Picture3 : </label><input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" /><br />
        <label for="image">Image : </label><input type="file" name="image" id="pic3" /><br />

                    <label for="nom">Picture4 : </label><input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" /><br />
        <label for="image">Image : </label><input type="file" name="image" id="pic4" /><br />


 <br>
        <label for="validation">Valider : </label><input type="submit" name="validation" id="validation" value="Envoyer" />
    </p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the traitement.php file:

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['validation'])) {

 if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
    echo 'Un problème est survenu durant l opération. Veuillez réessayer !';
 else {

    $extensions = array('/png', '/gif', '/jpg', '/jpeg');

    //récupère la chaîne à partir du dernier / pour connaître l'extension
    $extension = strrchr($_FILES['image']['type'], '/');

    //vérifie si l'extension est dans notre tableau            
    if(!in_array($extension, $extensions))
        echo 'Vous devez uploader un fichier de type png, gif, jpg, jpeg.';
    else {         


        define('MAXSIZE', 300000);        
    if($_FILES['image']['size'] > MAXSIZE)
     echo 'Votre image est supérieure à la taille maximale de '.MAXSIZE.' octets';
        else {

            try {
                $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mybase', 'root', '');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                exit('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
            }


            $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                            $selected_val = $_POST['truc'];

            $req = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO images(id_pays_img,nom,img, extension) VALUES(:id_pays_img, :nom,:image, :type)");
            $req->execute(array(
                                    'id_pays_img'=>$_POST['truc'],
                'nom' => $_POST['nom'],
                //'description' => $_POST['description'],
                'image' => $image,
                'type' => $_FILES['image']['type']
                ));

            echo 'operation succesed !';
         }
      }
   }
   }
   ?>
```

This code works well with one picture, but I didn't know how to do to save 4 pictures at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use different names in your form, i.e. `image1`, `image2` ... or an array with `image[]`. In the latter case your will have to take care of how the subelements can be accessed as described here:

http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.files.php